# Sort list of string numbers that are in a column of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame whose one column contains lists of string number

```
Col1
['1']
['1']
['1','3','4']
['2','3','1','4','5']
```

How can I sort this number? I have tried to adapt the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67490783/sorting-a-column-of-lists-of-strings-by-the-containing-number%20but%20I%20am%20not%20able%20to%20get%20it).

I would like to have a sorted list of integers instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
In [599]: df['Col1'] = df.Col1.apply(lambda x: sorted(map(int, x)))
In [600]: df
Out[600]: 
              Col1
0              [1]
1              [1]
2        [1, 3, 4]
3  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This changes original string number in list.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Exactly. Please read OP's comment: `I would like to have a sorted list of integers instead of strings.`

Comment: Misunderstand that, `list` in your code is unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[['1'],['1'],['1','3','4'],['2','3','1','4','5']]})
# use a list comprehension in which map list elements to int and sort the list
df['sorted'] = [sorted(map(int, row)) for row in df['Col1']]
print(df)
              Col1           sorted
0              [1]              [1]
1              [1]              [1]
2        [1, 3, 4]        [1, 3, 4]
3  [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```